# Display html content in iframe via props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have a very simple reusable component that is intended to display some HTML passed via props.

```
export class HtmlPreview extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.rendered.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = this.props.body;
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <iframe ref={(iframe) => this.rendered}></iframe>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And image I am calling this Component like:

```
<HtmlPreview body={'<h1>Hello World</h1>'}/>
```

However I always get a blank iframe with no content if it doesn't complain for `.contentDocument` not existing in an undefined object.

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using an iframe? You can use an iframe to display another URL, e.g.

```
import React from 'react';

const HtmlPreview = ({ url }) => <iframe src={url} title="myIframe" />;

export default HtmlPreview;
```

If you want to display just a HTML preview, you could just have a div with a scrollbar:

```
import React from 'react';

const HtmlPreview = ({ children }) => (
  <div style={{ width: 200, height: 200, overflowY: 'scroll' }}>{children}</div>
);

export default HtmlPreview;
```

And use it as follows:

```
<HtmlPreview><h1>My Preview</h1></HtmlPreview>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Scott, I also dont get ide of iframe there. Is the html that is passed as a prop a plain string? If it is, you should use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML".
https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Answer (score 0):

I was missing assigning the `iframe` reference to the variable inside the Component.

```
iframe ref={(iframe) => this.rendered = iframe}></iframe>
```

This allows to set `this.rendered` content inside the class methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a good use case for this idea.
Essentially, you want to display a preview for a user-uploaded html document which may contain its own CSS styles. If you load it via dangerouslySetInnerHtml the CSS styles may override site styles. By containing it within an iframe you avoid this issue and get the render the html document as if it were standalone without affecting the rest of the site.

My approach was as follows:

```
const PreviewHtml = (props) => {
  const {html} = props;

  return <iframe onload={e => e.currentTarget.contentDocument.body.innerHtml = html} />
}
```

You can of course make it more sophisticated by controlling load state, error checking, etc. This is just a PoC